# How to Get Blob with its Blob Properties from Azure using MULE 4

Tags: azure, mule4

Just wanted to ask what connector should we use to get the blob together with its blob properties, from Azure Storage, using MULE 4?

Thank you!
Regards,
Jin

Comment: I guess Azure has lots of services, like AWS. Exactly from which service is this blob you want to get? Is it from an SQL Server database? Your question has to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's from Azure Storage

Answer (score 0):

You can search for connectors at [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange). For Azure Storage there is one connector from a MuleSoft partner WHISHWORKS: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.modules/azure-storage-connector/. You'll have to reach to WHISHWORKS about the licensing terms. Reading the documentation of the connector it is not clear if it supports reading the blob properties.

If the connector doesn't provide the desired functionality then you can try using [Azure Blob Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) directly. Or alternatively you can use [Azure Client libraries for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-java-stable) and create your own connector using [Mule SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started).